# How to pass a variable (besides a set of records) from a controller to a razor view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have an api controller and a viewmodel as given below that fetch a set of records from an sql db and pass it to a razor view into a kendo grid.

Viewmodel:

```
    public class SoonDueReportsViewModel
{
    public SoonDueReportsViewModel()
    {
    }
    public string ARAName { get; set; }
    public int? ReportAraId { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public int? CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string  ReportDetails { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DueReportDate { get; set; }
    public int ReportId { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
    public class AllDueReportsController : BaseApiController
{
    private readonly IIdentityStorage identityStorage;

    public IQueryable<SoonDueReportsViewModel> Get()
    {

        AppKatPrincipal appKatPrincipal = identityStorage.GetPrincipal();

        var araIds = UnitOfWork.GetAll<UserGroup>()
            .Where(group => group.Id == appKatPrincipal.GroupId)
            .SelectMany(group => group.ARA).Select(ara => ara.Id);

        var duties = UnitOfWork.GetAll<Duty>();
        var companies = UnitOfWork.GetAll<Company>();
        var aras = UnitOfWork.GetAll<ARA>().Where(x => araIds.Contains(x.Id));

        var userGroupId = indireKatPrincipal.GroupId;
        var userGroup = UnitOfWork.GetById<UserGroup>(userGroupId);

        var foreRun = userGroup.ForRun.GetValueOrDefault();
        var nextDate = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(foreRun);   // The value of this variable I need to transport also to the view !!

        var query = from ara in aras
                    join company in companies on ara.Id equals company.ARA
                    join duty in duties on company.Id equals duty.CompanyId
                    where duty.ReportedDate == null
                    && company.Activ == true
                    select new SoonDueReportsViewModel
                    {
                        ARAName = ara.Name,
                        ReportAraId = ara.Id,
                        CompanyName = company.Name,
                        CompanyId = company.ID,
                        ReportDetails = duty.Details,
                        DueReportDate = duty.ReportDate,
                        ReportId = duty.Id,
                    };

        return query;
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, but in addition to the set of records (defined by the query) I also need to transport the value of the variable  'nextDate' to the same view.

If someone could give me a hint how to do this, I'd appreciate it a lot.
Regards, Manu

Comment: `ViewBag.NextDate = nextDate;`.. Then in your view use `ViewBag.NextDate`

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid: The api controller does not have a ViewBag.

Comment: The proper way to do this would be to create a VM that has a list of SoonDueReports, as well as a DateTime attribute.  Then set your `VM.SoonDueReports = query.ToList();` and `VM.NextDate = ....`

Comment: @Manu ahh okay then see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188367/pass-value-from-apicontroller-to-view-in-asp-net-mvc4)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pass value from apicontroller to view in asp.net mvc4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188367/pass-value-from-apicontroller-to-view-in-asp-net-mvc4)